# Psexec - how to output error encountered to a txt file

Tags: logging, cmd, psexec

Want to be able to output error encountered by psexce to be logged in txt file

e.g. unable to access computer, as i am attempting to connect to 30+ computers, over night.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest approach:

```
2>results.txt
```

add to the end of the batch file

thanks! @JosefZ